# What is this Windows 8 icon for as rectangle icon in the title bar?

Tags: windows, user-interface

Every Window in Windows 8 got this icon if it gots the focus. When clicking on it, nothing seems to happen.

How does this icon work?

[image: Windows 8 rectangle icon]

Comment: I have Windows 8 and I do not see that icon

Comment: On @Devid suggestion, have you installed any theme or desktop-altering software?

Comment: No i have not. I also guess this is from some kind third party software.

Comment: It sure is from third party software.

Comment: @Devid I was asking the OP, not you...

Comment: @Devid thanks you are right. After using Process Explorer, I found the application hook.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Dell Premier Color](http://www.portrait.com/dtune/dl2/deu/upgrade.html) Icon for Windows 8, if more than one screen is connected (Multiscreen) to send any Window to the other screen. 
[image: Dell Display Splitter]